# mask linked data across two columns

Tags: pandas, merge, grouping

This is an subset of huge dataset, I want that all the numbers in ID-2 columns linked directly or indirectly to 1 in ID-1 to be grouped next to 1, same with 2 and so on.

```
   ID1  ID2
0    1    2
1    1    4
2    2    6
3    2    5
4    3    7
```

to:

```
  ID1  ID2
0   1    2
1        4
2        6
3        5
4   3    7
```

Comment: please don't upload images of data/code/errors/etc for a [variety of reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/). instead, just copy the result of `print(df)` and paste it into your question as a code block. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
# map ID2 values to ID1 or keep ID1
s = df['ID1'].map(df.set_index('ID2')['ID1']).fillna(df['ID1'])

# mask duplicated values
df.loc[s.duplicated(), 'ID1'] = ''
```

output:

```
  ID1  ID2
0   1    2
1        4
2        6
3        5
4   3    7
```

If you prefer a new column:

```
s = df['ID1'].map(df.set_index('ID2')['ID1']).fillna(df['ID1'])

df['new'] = df['ID1'].mask(s.duplicated(), '')
```

output:

```
   ID1  ID2 new
0    1    2   1
1    1    4    
2    2    6    
3    2    5    
4    3    7   3
```